# iOS error reporting when upload app

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I've tried to create a simple iOS application using Phonegap. I have followed the guidelines of phonegap to add 4 pieces of image: `res/screen/ios/` in  my app directory.

But when I upload the application, I get an error report like this.

`Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0.`

`Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0.`

`Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0.`

`Version Mismatch - Neither CFBundleVersion ['1.0.0'] nor CFBundleShortVersionString [''] in the Info.plist match the version of the app set in iTunes Connect ['1.0'].`

What should I do and add to resolve this error?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to develope icons as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html). So include icons as it is saying like `'120x120'`, `'76x76'`  and `'152x152'`

And for version mismatch, whenever you release an application there is a concept of versioning so on iTunesConnect you have set it correct to `1.0`, but you have to also include in your info.plist file within your application. For more details check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1)